# Kubernetes - In AWS EKS Fargate How Can I Send Logs From One Container To FluentD For Splunk?

Tags: logging, kubernetes, fluentd, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I have no idea how to do this. Any help would be great.

I'm running a pod on Fargate that holds my application container and a fluentd container. How can I send my logs from my application container to my fluentd container to push to splunk? I cannot set my log driver or log options (the normal way I would configure my container to change it's log destination) in my kubernetes deployment definition.

So how am I suppose to accomplish this, has anyone actually done this?

Comment: Changed the docker so it logs to a file and shares the directory between fluentd and itself. So fluentd now has access to the logs... i think. It just still isn't sending it to splunk, however I think* its a fluentd configuration at this point.

log drivers are not available in kubernetes deployments, which makes my life a nightmare at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works today is by making sure you are logging to a file and then add a Fluentxxx sidecar to the pod so that it can grab the log and send it to a destination. This is because there is no way (other than using interactively `kubectl logs` ) to grab logs printed to stdout (yet).

However we are working on [this feature](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/701) that will allow EKS/Fargate customers to 1) not bother about using a sidecar and 2) grab stdout logs out of the box.

The idea is that you will only need to specify a per cluster / per ns / per pod logging configuration and we will send the logs to supported (popular) destinations.